# Android webview not loading xampp server url

Tags: java, android

First of all I've set my INTERNET manifest permissions correctly.

I'm working on an android app which utilizes webview; and i'm trying to load a custom page I created which resides on the network at (XAMPP)10.0.0.11. My android device is on same network and Apache is started.

In my app, im using webview.loadurl("http://10.0.0.11/") and it doesn't seem to work, changing the string to "www.google.com" works fine. What could be the problem? Help pls!

Comment: Can you reach the website through your phones browser?

Comment: I swiched wifi networks and it works fine now. Thanks!